# Question about variables like '$xml' and others

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

What do these variables stand for? like `$xml`, `$messages`, `$config` and some other variables start with '$'. Are there any documents to describe how these variables work?

Comment: In addition to what Chris mentioned, the $ sign is just a naming convention for some of these oft-used utility objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to download the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 GUI Extensions API from [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF) (requires log in)